# Making dynamic variable/list in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm writing a telegrambot, and I want to use custom keyboard. So the keyboard layout is 3 by 3 it is a numpad from 1-9 (technically). The code I used is the following:

```
keyboard =  [['' + str(places[0]) + '', '' + str(places[1]) + '', '' + str(places[2]) + ''],
            ['' + str(places[3]) + '', '' + str(places[4]) + '', '' + str(places[5]) + ''],
            ['' + str(places[2]) + '', '' + str(places[7]) + '', '' + str(places[8]) + '']]
```

This is my places (array/list): `places = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`
This is the result in real world:(without brackets and commas)

```
[[1],[2],[3],
 [4],[5],[6],
 [7],[8],[9]]
```

I'm removing items from the array (randomly, but one at the time(at user input)), and I want to replace the missing position at the keyboard with an " " (space) like this: `[" "]`. I need this, because this way the user can not send the same number twice, but I need an empty space to send the keyboard to telegram api, or else it crashez.

Please help me to deal with it, because I'm  a beginner in python, and mostly in programming. I tried to make it with for cycle, but not sure how to do it correctly.

This is what I tried (it is incomplete, because I got really confused):

```
lenght = len(places)

row_starter = '['
row_ender = ']'

keyboard = '['
for i in (1,3):
    keyboard = keyboard + row_starter
    for j in (1,3):
       #don't know what to do :(

    keyboard = keyboard + row_ender 
    keyboard = keyboard + ']'
```

Please help me deal with it.

P.S.: Please let me know If you don't understand something, I'm VERY bad at explaining. And please don't look at my english I'm still learning it. (If you want I can add an expected outcome to the description.)
**Thank you soo much!!!**

Comment: Instead of creating a string representation of the board **and then** manipulating it, create a list representation of the board that is more easily manipulated, and then create a function that converts that to the string board.

Comment: Here is a better way to initialize ```keyboard```:  ```keyboard = [str(x).center(3) for x in range(1,10)]``` and then ```keyboard = [keyboard[:3], keyboard[3:6], keyboard[6:9]]```.

Comment: So, for example, take your `places = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`. If the user inputs `4`, simply do `places[user_input - 1] = " "` and then do your `keyboard = ` computation to create the board print out with the intended `4` removed and replaced with " ". Your problem is that *you made your task harder then it needed to be.* ;)

Comment: @FelipeFaria I'm sorry, but it is not working for me.
the original: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`
user_input = 1
this is the output: `[' ', 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`
If I give it a 9 as an input is is just crashes with this: `IndexError: list assignment index out of range`
For the first comment can you please make an example code for me? I'd be so happy :)
@accdias thanks it is working flawlessly (it is a bit magic for me, but cool :) ) But how can I replace some numbers with the space char?

Comment: @FelipeFaria Something was wrong with my code, I remade some functions, and now your code makes the right change :) thanks 

Is there any ways to combine this [" "] method with the keyboard code?

Comment: @Skeleton022 [Functions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/functions-in-python/)! You can do the following: (1) Create a function that takes your list, and prints it out. (2) Create a function that removes (replaces) an index from the list and returns the modified list (described above in the comments). (3) Create a variable `command = None`, and do a `while command != -1:` and in the loop `command = input("What item to remove? (-1 to exit)")` with the `places = remove_index(list, index)` and `print_list(places)`.